Couldn't install pods when running npx install-expo-modules@latest
So Im trying to install expo modules from my React-Native-App project. WHen I run the command I get the following error:

› Installing ios pods...
pod install
Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
pod install --repo-update
Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
Uncaught Error CocoaPodsError: Command pod install failed.
└─ Cause: spawn pod ENOENT

...

code: 'COMMAND_FAILED',
cause: Error: spawn pod ENOENT
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn pod',
path: 'pod',
spawnargs: [ 'install', '--repo-update', '--ansi' ],
pid: undefined,
output: [ '', '' ],
stdout: '',
stderr: '',
status: null,
signal: null
},
isPackageManagerError: true
}

I tried gem install cocoapods but it failes with:

Ignoring ffi-1.12.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

